# editing a slug post in django

Tags: python, django

I have an application where user create posts and can view them. the problem I face is with the edit button and how to make only users who created the post be able to edit their own post or delete them else another user can not. if I enter into the browser url field  for example `http://127.0.0.1:8000/soko/edit` it opens the form field and it is ready to be edited but if I use input button from my template I get the following error `Reverse for 'edit' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<slug>[\\w-]+)/edit/$']`

below is my **views.py**

```
def edit(request, slug = None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug = slug)
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance = instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        messages.success(request, "Post updated")
        #redirecting to landing page
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())

    context = {
        "title": instance.title,
        "instance": instance,
        "form": form,
    }
    template = 'edit.html'
    return render(request, template, context)

def delete(request, slug=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    instance.delete()
    messages.success(request, "Post Deleted")
    return redirect(index)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/edit/$', views.edit, name='edit'),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/delete/$', views.delete, name='delete'),
```

**html**

`<a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'posts:edit' %}"></a>`

**forms.py**

```
 class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post

        fields = [
            "title",
            "content",
        ]
```

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 120)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique= True)
    content = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("posts:more", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

Comment: How do you handle the user instance in your form ? share your form code and your Post model.

Comment: done @misraX added the form

Comment: I just had to pass the instance to the  view

Comment: form.py and models.py not your template, it's important because your code doesn't show any relation with the User model.

Comment: i have added the form and model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Post model has no relation with the User model so to include the user instance in your form or views that relates to your Post model you need to add a relation like so:

```
# models.py

# include the User model
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    .....
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

And your views have to handle the requested user and it's relation with the instance plus validating and restricting the request access.

```
# views.py
# restrict the view to only the user who created the instance.

from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

# A custom access decorator to check if the request.user 
# is the owner of the instance 
def  restrict_user_access(function):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        posts =  Post.objects.get(slug=kwargs['slug'])
        if post.created_by != request.user:
            raise PermissionDenied
        return function(request, *args, **kwargs)

    wrap.__doc__ = function.__doc__
    wrap.__name__ = function.__name__
    return wrap

@restrict_user_access
def edit(request, slug = None):
   instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug = slug)
   form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance =instance)
   if form.is_valid():
        ....
        # add the request.user to created_by
        form.instance.created_by = request.user
        form.save()

@restrict_user_access
def delete(request, slug=None):
    .....
```

The reverse error happens because django can't resolve your url without the slug pattern as you described in your `urls.py` so in your template you need to pass the post_context.slug in your url like so, change post_context to whatever context you are using in that view.

`<a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'posts:edit' post_context.slug %}"></a>`

edited: changed pk to slug.

Comment: Okay but this explains one part of the question and not the where I get errors

Comment: I don’t quite understand what u mean by post_context.slug

Comment: Alright, you mentioned that when you call http://127.0.0.1:8000/soko/edit in your browser you got no problem, so to pass this in your template url django tries to resolve your edit url with a slug pattern like soko, if there is no slug pattern there will be a reverse problem so you need to pass your post instance context.slug in your url to be resolved.

Comment: If we will talk about your edit view, The post context is the instance context, so instance.slug in your template is what I am talking about, this is the context that you need to pass it's slug value to your url to be resolved so in your edit view Template you can add this `<a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'posts:edit' instance.slug %}"></a>` and it will work :) I hope you understand now.

Comment: That fixed it Thank you very much but for the restrict_user_access function, how can I display a custom error message instead if the 404 forbidden error

Comment: It's 403 forbidden, you can simply create `403.html` in your base template directory and add your custom message check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/views/#the-403-http-forbidden-view

Comment: Thanks. You are my hero 